# Unable to find Sum of particular rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset in this form:

```
       crawled_fag   tech_flag    ug_flag
0         1              2           0
1         6              0           0
2         2              0           1
3         1              0           1
4         0              1           0
5         0              7           0
```

What I want here is that the second row should be equal to sum of all it's below rows.. For example, In crawled_flag column, the second row value should be 6+2+1+0+0 = 9...

Simillarly, this should be my final dataset:

```
        crawled_fag   tech_flag    ug_flag
0         1              2           0
1         9              8           2
```

Can someone please help me on how to achieve it..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for add summed all rows without first, last transpose `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1:].sum()], axis=1, ignore_index=True).T
print (df)
   crawled_fag  tech_flag  ug_flag
0            1          2        0
1            9          8        2
```